# Unknown piece of PHP

Tags: php

Oké. I saw this piece of code and I was curious about how it works and what it does.
Can anyone explain this to me?
Thanks!

```
$_SESSION['langtype']
   = (empty($_SESSION['langtype'])) ? 'false' : $_SESSION['langtype'];
```

Comment: it sets $_SESSION['langtype'] to false if it's not set. Otherwise it just sets it again with the current value

Comment: its a Ternary Operator view this link http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Shouldn't you use 'isset', if you're not sure if the array element is set? Because you see, if langtype was '0', it'd also set it to 'false'.

Comment: you might find this reference helpful: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139/367456)

Comment: it's an inline if: `(expression) ? <do when true> : <do when false>;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It puts false in `$_SESSION['langtype']` is the value is not set, otherwise it keeps the current value.

See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Answer (score 1):

It puts `"false"` in `$_SESSION['langtype']` (as a STRING, not BOOL VALUE) in case `$_SESSION['langtype']` is empty (or value with key `langtype` does not exist), otherwise keeps the same value.

It's probably bad idea to put `"false"` as a string. For example if the author of this masterpiece decides to do a check `if ($_SESSION['langtype']) { }`, it will return true in any case. I'm curious in which case this solution should be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Its a short hand for `if-else` statement. if `(empty($_SESSION['langtype']))` then `$_SESSION['langtype'] = false` else `$_SESSION['langtype'] = $_SESSION['langtype']`

Answer (score 1):

This is ternary Operator used in this Statement

```
$_SESSION['langtype'] = (empty($_SESSION['langtype'])) ? 'false' : $_SESSION['langtype'];
```

It means If Session variable named **langtype** is empty then return false, Otherwise use langtype same as defined

The portion after **?** represent the value if function

```
empty($_SESSION['langtype'])
```

returns true(Mean if it is empty then set it false or un-define that variable) i.e

```
$_SESSION['langtype'] = false;
```

and portion after **:** represent else statement that is if langtype is not empty then keep it as it is(Equal to Defined Value) as

```
$_SESSION['langtype']=$_SESSION['langtype'];
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called a ternary operator. it consists of condition expression, and return values for both evaluations of the condition.

```
// if expression evaluates to true first value will be returned,
// otherwise it will the second 
$variable = (expression) ? 'value if true' : 'value if false';
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is not set(true) then it will be false else if its (false) it ill print the session value

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['langtype'] = (empty($_SESSION['langtype'])) ? 'false' : $_SESSION['langtype'];
```

For a beginner the above code is the same as the long version which you might know

```
<?php
     if(empty($_SESSION['langtype'])) {
           $_SESSION['langtype'] = 'false';
     } else {
          $_SESSION['langtype'] =  $_SESSION['langtype'];
     }
 ?>
```